# Sometimes (specially in bibliographies) the \P complexity class is rendered as pilcrow

Tags: biber, complexity

A MWE is as follows. With texlive 20200327-30 from Fedora 34 (up to date) I get the `\P` rendered as '¶'.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{complexity}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{goldreich10:_p_np_np-complete,
  author =       {Goldreich, Oded},
  title =        {\P, \NP, and \NP-completeness:
                  The Basics of Computational Complexity},
  publisher =    {Cambridge University Press},
  year =         2010
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\P` is a standard latex command that produces the symbol you show.

Comment: your example is incomplete, does adding `\documentclass{article}` make an example of the problem?

Comment: biber knows that \P should be ¶ and translates it accordingly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes. Cut off when pasting in the file, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package provides `\cP` as a safer alternative, so this works

```
  title =        {\cP, \NP, and \NP-completeness:
```

`\P` is a standard LaTeX command for a character so biber expands it to that, so it can do sorting etc.

Comment: one can tell biber to leave some commands by setting up a recode xml and using it  with the `--decodecharsset` option (see the biber documentation), but imho using `\cP`  is less work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'd rather ask the package maintainer not to over-write core latex commands.

Comment: I would ask him not to define so many commands, the package seems to highjack nearly every short command name for itself ;-(.